# Rails Cache Expire at Certain Time in Time Zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've been trying to get the index action of a controller to expire the cache every night at 7:01 PM CST on an Amazon EC2 instance on Elastic Beanstalk.  It doesn't appear to be working and I'm not quite sure why.  I don't really wanna use a cron job because that's somewhat buggy with whenever-eb and I'm still vetting that, so I'd like to expire the cache with an explicit time directive.

Here is the code I am using.

```
 caches_action :index, :layout => false, :unless => proc { user_signed_in? },expires_in: Time.use_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)") { DateTime.now.in_time_zone(Time.zone).beginning_of_day + 19.hours + 1.minute }
```

Any idea on where I am going wrong?

To further that is there a better way to expire all caches at 7:01 PM CST in one method call?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion the best way to expire your cache is on data change.  What is the reason you wish to expire the cache at a specific time?  Maybe you can use a version of "Time Based Expiry" but I've only seen that used to expire cached content hours after an action.

Comment: Hi @BrianKunzig...I do understand your point, but the problem is that I have information going to the DB (updated/created in the DB) at any given time.  The data is set to be displayed at 7PM CST.  So there is not an 'update' that can be used to expire the cache.

Comment: Would expiring the cache on create/destroy be useful?  If so you can use sweepers to expire the cache on any DB exchange saved using the 'rails-observers' gem and writing a quick sweeper method. Aside from that, you may have to resort to using a scheduled task via whenever-eb

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveSupport::Cache::Store, you can do the following:

```
<% cache(key, :expires_in => 12.hours) do %>
   <!-- content -->
<% end %>
```

Here's a link to the docs:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration